# Unable to open port 10241 under Debian 8.5

Tags: linux, binding, port

I have a test game server running under virtualized Debian 8.5 (VirtualBox under Windows 10) ; this Linux machine has its own IP address in network.
Game server use ports 2106, 7777 and 10241. I successfully configured my box to make the game server available from WAN, these 3 ports are redirected to Linux machine IP 192.168.1.70 (tests are made from my Windows machine 192.168.1.1).

I made some telnet tests from Windows, like :

```
telnet 192.168.1.70 2106 ==> Test OK
telnet 192.168.1.70 7777 ==> Test OK
telnet MY_PUBLIC_IP 2106 ==> Test OK
telnet MY_PUBLIC_IP 7777 ==> Test OK
telnet 192.168.1.70 10241 ==> Test KO !!
telnet MY_PUBLIC_IP 10241 ==> Test KO !!
```

At the same time, I tcdump packets from Linux machine and have for port 2106:

```
23:10:50.525372 IP 192.168.1.1.55598 > 192.168.1.70.2106: Flags [S], seq 2926133714, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
23:10:50.525398 IP 192.168.1.70.2106 > 192.168.1.1.55598: Flags [S.], seq 2509536992, ack 2926133715, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:10:50.525493 IP 192.168.1.1.55598 > 192.168.1.70.2106: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2053, length 0
23:10:50.526496 IP 192.168.1.70.2106 > 192.168.1.1.55598: Flags [P.], seq 1:187, ack 1, win 229, length 186
23:10:50.526555 IP 192.168.1.1.55598 > 192.168.1.70.2106: Flags [.], ack 187, win 2052, length 0
```

And for port 10241 :

```
23:06:38.490407 IP 192.168.1.1.55536 > 192.168.1.70.10241: Flags [S], seq 1465108966, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
23:06:38.490431 IP 192.168.1.70.10241 > 192.168.1.1.55536: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
23:06:38.990784 IP 192.168.1.1.55536 > 192.168.1.70.10241: Flags [S], seq 1465108966, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
23:06:38.990815 IP 192.168.1.70.10241 > 192.168.1.1.55536: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
```

Result of `nmap -sT -O localhost`:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-02-17 23:12 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000084s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
2106/tcp open  ekshell
3306/tcp open  mysql
7777/tcp open  cbt
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 3.7 - 3.15
Network Distance: 0 hops
```

And netstat -tulpn (removed useless ports) :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56069           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      473/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      883/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::9014                 :::*                    LISTEN      3796/java
tcp6       0      0 :::2106                 :::*                    LISTEN      3796/java
tcp6       0      0 :::7777                 :::*                    LISTEN      3811/java
```

I have no firewall configured into Linux machine (this is a test machine, not a live machine), only default Debian IPtable. Has someone any idea of what I can do to open this port ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your netstat command tcp 10241 is not listening.
You can try following to check.

```
 netstat -a|grep 10241

 nc -u localhost 10241
```

this will give you some indication. may be it is listening on a UDP port.

Comment: The first command didn't make any return, and the second one is sent but nothing happens

Comment: Any other idea ?